# Selenium combo throwing an error on element_id_from

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting an error if I try to use Selenium as my driver instead of webkit.

This happens if the driver is set: `Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome` or `Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_firefox`

The root call is: `click_on 'Create account'`.  However it happens for any find call.

```
    TypeError:
      no implicit conversion of String into Integer
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/bridge_helper.rb:47:in `[]'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/bridge_helper.rb:47:in `element_id_from'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:606:in `block in find_elements_by'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:606:in `each'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:606:in `map'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:606:in `find_elements_by'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.52.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:84:in `find_elements'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/selenium/driver.rb:69:in `find_xpath'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:107:in `find_xpath'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/query.rb:110:in `block in resolve_for'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:80:in `synchronize'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/query.rb:106:in `resolve_for'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:35:in `block in find'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/base.rb:84:in `synchronize'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/finders.rb:33:in `find'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/node/actions.rb:13:in `click_link_or_button'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/capybara-2.6.2/lib/capybara/session.rb:686:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Session>'
      # /Users/aaron/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.6/gems/capybara-angular-0.2.3/lib/capybara/angular/dsl.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <module:DSL>'
      # ./spec/features/pokitdok_pdpc_spec.rb:42:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Additionally, if I replace the method call with the functionality and pry it, it looks like the wrong object type is being passed in:

```
[6] pry(#<Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Bridge>)> ids.map{|id| puts id.inspect; Element.new self, (id['ELEMENT'] or id['element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf'])}
["acceptSslCerts", true]
TypeError: no implicit conversion of String into Integer
  from (pry):6:in `[]'
```

Capybara Version: 2.6.2
Selenium Webdriver Version: 2.52.0

Driver Definitions:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium_chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome)
end

Capybara.register_driver :selenium_firefox do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :firefox)
end
```

Browser Versions
  Chrome: 48.0.2564.109 (64-bit)
  Firefox: 44.0.2

Selenium 2.52.0 should be recent enough to cover them.

Code:

```rb
require "spec_helper"

describe "Pokitdok PDPC", type: :feature, js: true do
  let!(:payer) { FactoryGirl.create(:payer, :pokitdok, name: 'Mock Payer') }
  let!(:clinic_population_group) { FactoryGirl.create(:clinic_population_group, population_group: payer, public_name: payer.name) }
  let(:user) do
    {
      first_name: 'Eligible', #Look at PokitdokMock
      last_name: 'Patient', #Look at PokitdokMock
    }
  end

  before :each do
    Capybara.current_driver = :selenium_chrome
    visit '/'
  end

  context 'clinic' do
    let(:clinic) { clinic_population_group.clinic }

    before :each do
      stub_production_environment
      PokitdokMock.load_webmocks
    end
    it 'registers a PDPC payer on accurate data' do
      click_on 'Create account'
    end
  end
end
```

Gemfile.lock

```
capybara (2.6.2)
  addressable
  mime-types (>= 1.16)
  nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
  rack (>= 1.0.0)
  rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
  xpath (~> 2.0)
capybara-angular (0.2.3)
  capybara (>= 2.5.0)
capybara-firebug (2.1.0)
  capybara (>= 1.0, < 3.0)
  selenium-webdriver
capybara-screenshot (1.0.11)
  capybara (>= 1.0, < 3)
  launchy
capybara-webkit (1.8.0)
  capybara (>= 2.3.0, < 2.7.0)
  json
chromedriver-helper (1.0.0)
  archive-zip (~> 0.7.0)
  nokogiri (~> 1.6)
rspec (3.4.0)
  rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
rspec-core (3.4.3)
  rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
rspec-expectations (3.4.0)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
rspec-mocks (3.4.1)
  diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
rspec-rails (3.4.2)
  actionpack (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
  activesupport (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
  railties (>= 3.0, < 4.3)
  rspec-core (~> 3.4.0)
  rspec-expectations (~> 3.4.0)
  rspec-mocks (~> 3.4.0)
  rspec-support (~> 3.4.0)
rspec-support (3.4.1)
selenium-webdriver (2.52.0)
  childprocess (~> 0.5)
  multi_json (~> 1.0)
  rubyzip (~> 1.0)
  websocket (~> 1.0)
```

---

**UPDATE**

The error is happening in this function:

```rb
def element_id_from(id)
  id['ELEMENT'] or id['element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf']
end
```

id being passed in is:

```rb
{"cssSelectorsEnabled"=>true, "browserName"=>"firefox", "handlesAlerts"=>true, "javascriptEnabled"=>true, "nativeEvents"=>false, "platform"=>"Darwin", "rotatable"=>false, "takesScreenshot"=>true, "version"=>"44.0.2", "webStorageEnabled"=>true, "applicationCacheEnabled"=>true, "databaseEnabled"=>true, "locationContextEnabled"=>true, "acceptSslCerts"=>true}
```

That value is coming from `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Http::Common#call`

```rb
request verb, url, headers, payload
```

with the values

```rb
#Not passed in as a hash, just did it for printing purposes
{
  verb: post
  url: http://127.0.0.1:7055/hub/session/3c3f8527-5ef5-8b42-b5e4-c46bfdfb4b78/elements
  headers: {"Accept"=>"application/json", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=utf-8", "Content-Length"=>"646"}
  payload: {"using":"xpath","value":".//a[./@href][(((./@id = 'Create account' or normalize-space(string(.)) = 'Create account') or ./@title = 'Create account') or .//img[./@alt = 'Create account'])] | .//input[./@type = 'submit' or ./@type = 'reset' or ./@type = 'image' or ./@type = 'button'][((./@id = 'Create account' or ./@value = 'Create account') or ./@title = 'Create account')] | .//input[./@type = 'image'][./@alt = 'Create account'] | .//button[(((./@id = 'Create account' or ./@value = 'Create account') or normalize-space(string(.)) = 'Create account') or ./@title = 'Create account')] | .//input[./@type = 'image'][./@alt = 'Create account']"}
}
```

Comment: What are your definitions for the drivers :seleneium_chrome and :selenium_firefox

Comment: @TomWalpole added to the post

Comment: hmmm -- no clue unless you have something messing with the communications between selenium-webdriver and the browser-- Capybaras tests pass fine with 2.52.0

Comment: What version of firefox ? and chrome ?

Comment: @TomWalpole It does appear to be using the remote bridge instead of the chrome or firefox bridge.  I don't know if that has anything to do with anything.  Browsers added

Comment: The firefox/chrome bridges are derived from the remote bridge as seen -  here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/bridge.rb#L25

Comment: Yeah - I'm using FF 44.0.2 with selenium-webdriver 2.52.0 and not seeing any issues -- you don't have something like VCR setup thats recording the comms between selenium and the browser and replaying incorrectly or anything? Or just because it's responding with "acceptSslCerts" are you connecting over SSL without correct certs or something?

Comment: also please add a short example test that results in the error - just to make sure it's not something you're doing previously

Comment: @TomWalpole Added code.  

I don't have VCR set up.  I do have headless set up, but it's conditional, it's not being run.  Using DBCleaner and reset_sessions! around each example.

I was just trying to show that it was returning an array, not a hash.  Then ids['ELEMENT'] is being called on an array which is invalid syntax.

Comment: It's strange, the only thing I can suggest would be to uninstall/reinstall selenium (the firefox installed client is included there), or make sure you're using the latest chromedriver for chrome.  From all the info it looks like the code installed into the browser is actually returning the wrong type of data which rules out Capybara as the issue.

Comment: @TomWalpole  I cleaned out my rvm environment, reinstalled everything, still have the same issue.  I've also added my capybara related gems in the post.

Comment: From the chromedriver-helper readme -- you might need to force it to update your chromedriver - https://github.com/flavorjones/chromedriver-helper#updating-chromedriver   - at the very least check your version of the chromedriver binary and see if its the latest

Comment: @TomWalpole Unfortunately that didn't do it. I'm more convinced that it's a Selenium-webdriver issue though.